# Save a perfect configured desktop

Tags: backup, administration, persistence

I'm wondering how I can persist my perfect configured desktop system.

I have
- installed a fresh new debian
- installed all my applications and tools I need (from vim to eclipse)
- override my systems bashrc/-.profile etc
- installed and configured my wm (fluxbox and themes)

So now this was a lot of work and Im looking for a way to "save" /export that state. I want to be able to recover my system after a reinstall or dublicate it (in case of using it in VMs).

I was thinking of exporting the list of installed packages as well as some dot-files but im not sure, that this is the best choice. What would you recomend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did it correctly then all your changes are in your $HOME. Just copy that $HOME folder around and your done.

If you don't want to copy the entire folder then ~/.local/config is a good place to start, but your better off just copying over the entire folder.

Comment: Sounds too easy somehow :D So you mean I can than simply reinstall a fresh debian and just copy and override the backuped home-directory on my new system?

Comment: Yep.  123456789012345

Comment: I know this is getting ole, but I'm trying to do something similar.  This is an actual question, not a criticism...  What about the installed apps, like vim, etc?  Their modified settings are in the home directory, but not the programs themselves, or their global settings.

Comment: You should never modify global settings for applications. Instead you should modify your user's settings. With that said, when you need a program just reinstall it. The setting will be picked up from $HOME.  If your really want to `dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list` then `sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list`  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages

Answer (score 1):

A list of installed packages and dotfiles in your home is a good bet.

The management of dotfiles is a sort of art, check

https://dotfiles.github.io/